# Qt 5.5 QDateTime::addSec function has returned a wrong value in a last day of a month if add 12 hours (43200 secs)

Tags: qt, qt5.5

Qt 5.5 QDateTime::addSec function has returned a wrong value in a last day of a month if add 12 hours (43200 secs).

I's got the following result today 30 november 2015:

1.

```
QDateTime::currentDateTimeUtc().addSecs(43200);
```

output (run time - 2015-11-30T10:05:50):

```
date - Mon Nov 30 10:05:50 2015 GMT
```

2.

```
QDateTime::currentDateTimeUtc().addSecs(21600);
```

output (run time - 2015-11-30T10:08:12):

```
date - Mon Nov 30 16:08:12 2015 GMT
```

3.

```
QDateTime::currentDateTimeUtc().addDays(1).addSecs(-43200);
```

output (run time - 2015-11-30T10:11:08):

```
date - Tue Dec 1 10:11:08 2015 GMT
```

I want to add 12 hours and get 2015-11-30T22:11:08
How to avoid this situation? Is it a bug in Qt or I do something wrong?

Comment: I'm using Qt 5.5.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 and for me it works correctly.

Comment: it's on Qt5.5.0, windows based.

Comment: Can you convert your example to use QDateTime(2015, 11, 30, …) instead of currentDateTime(), so that it can be still reproduced tomorrow?

Comment: I wrote a small example. And everything works as expected. I think It's environment issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a small example. And everything works as expected. I think It's environment issue. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Note that `QDateTime QDateTime::addSecs(int s) const` is a const function, that means, it does not change `this` object. You need to evaluate the returned object:

```
QDateTime dt = QDateTime::currentDateTimeUtc().addSecs(43200);
... output dt ...
```

Also from the latest documentation (Qt Documentation for version 4.8 did not have this):

> Note that the time will wrap if it passes midnight.

Whatever this means...

Comment: I thought the same, but I think the OP is printing the output directly since case 3 does give a correct output.